# Long JSON string causing error "assert failed: xQueueSemaphoreTake queue.c:1545 (( pxQueue ))" at (*mtx).lock()

Tags: string, base64, semaphore, esp32, progmem

I am trying to process a favicon for a Minecraft server based upon the esp32-minecraft-server project (https://github.com/nikisalli/esp32-minecraft-server).

I have modified minecraft.cpp (https://github.com/nikisalli/esp32-minecraft-server/blob/main/lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp) so that instead of using the writeString function in the writeResponse function, I am instead saving a long string containing the favicon data (formatted in base64) into PROGMEM and loading it byte by byte. I thought this might stop the ESP32 from crashing and rebooting which happens when the string is over 5997 bytes (discovered through trial and error).

writeResponse Function (No Edits)

```
void minecraft::player::writeResponse(){
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0);
    p.writeString("{\"version\": {\"name\": \"1.16.5\",\"protocol\": 754},\"players\": {\"max\": 5,\"online\": 5,\"sample\": [{\"name\": \"L_S___S_S_S__S_L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"},{\"name\": \"L_SS__S_S_S_S__L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001\"},{\"name\": \"L_S_S_S_S_SS___L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002\"},{\"name\": \"L_S__SS_S_S_S__L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003\"},{\"name\": \"L_S___S_S_S__S_L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004\"}]},\"description\": {\"text\": \"esp32 server\"}}");
    logout("response packet sent");
    p.writePacket();
}
```

writeResponse Function (Modified)

```
void minecraft::player::writeResponse() {
    packet p(S, mtx);
    p.writeVarInt(0);
    // Define the string in PROGMEM
    const char response[] PROGMEM = "{\"version\": {\"name\": \"1.16.5\",\"protocol\": 754},\"players\": {\"max\": 5,\"online\": 5,\"sample\": [{\"name\": \"L_S___S_S_S__S_L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"},{\"name\": \"L_SS__S_S_S_S__L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001\"},{\"name\": \"L_S_S_S_S_SS___L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002\"},{\"name\": \"L_S__SS_S_S_S__L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003\"},{\"name\": \"L_S___S_S_S__S_L\",\"id\": \"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004\"}]},\"description\": {\"text\": \"esp32 server\"},\"favicon\":\"data:image/png;base64,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\"}";
    // Get the length of the string
    size_t responseLength = strlen_P(response);
    // Write the length of the string
    p.writeVarInt(responseLength);
    // Read and write the string byte by byte
    for (size_t i = 0; i < responseLength; ++i) {
        p.write(pgm_read_byte(&response[i]));
    }
    logout("response packet sent");
    p.writePacket();
}
```

I have discovered the code fails at (*mtx).lock() in the writePacket function. This is the same point the error was occurring when I was using the writeString function with an equally long string.

```
void packet::writePacket(){
    Serial.println("BEFORE LOCK");
    (*mtx).lock();
    Serial.println("AFTER LOCK");
    serverWriteVarInt(index);
    S->write(buffer, index);
    (*mtx).unlock();
}
```

Here is the serial output. The error occurs when I load the Minecraft server details in the Multiplayer menu:

```
 *  Executing task: C:\Users\Elect\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe device monitor 


Please build project in debug configuration to get more details about an exception.
See [https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf/build_configurations.html][3]


--- Terminal on COM11 | 115200 8-N-1
--- Available filters and text transformations: colorize, debug, default, direct, esp32_exception_decoder, hexlify, log2file, nocontrol, printable, send_on_enter, time
--- More details at
--- Quit: Ctrl+C | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H
e[    65][E][esConnecting to WiFi...
Connected to the WiFi network
172.20.10.5
[INFO] server started
[INFO] New client connected: 0
[INFO] p0 started task 0 pinned to core 0
[INFO] p0 <- request packet received
[INFO] p0 -> response packet sent
BEFORE LOCK

assert failed: xQueueSemaphoreTake queue.c:1545 (( pxQueue ))


Backtrace: 0x40083669:0x3ffecbd0 0x4008bbd9:0x3ffecbf0 0x40091059:0x3ffecc10 0x4008cbe9:0x3ffecd40 0x40082936:0x3ffecd80 0x4008294f:0x3ffecda0 0x400d3080:0x3ffecdc0 0x400d5136:0x3ffecde0 0x400d54bf:0x3fff0890 0x400d2a81:0x3fff0910

  #0  0x40083669:0x3ffecbd0 in panic_abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_system/panic.c:408
  #1  0x4008bbd9:0x3ffecbf0 in esp_system_abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_system/esp_system.c:137
  #2  0x40091059:0x3ffecc10 in __assert_func at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/newlib/assert.c:85
  #3  0x4008cbe9:0x3ffecd40 in xQueueSemaphoreTake at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/queue.c:1549 (discriminator 1)
  #4  0x40082936:0x3ffecd80 in pthread_mutex_lock_internal at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/pthread/pthread.c:620
  #5  0x4008294f:0x3ffecda0 in pthread_mutex_lock at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/pthread/pthread.c:650
  #6  0x400d3080:0x3ffecdc0 in packet::writePacket() at c:\users\elect\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch5\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\no-rtti\bits/gthr-default.h:761
      (inlined by) std::mutex::lock() at c:\users\elect\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32@8.4.0+2021r2-patch5\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/std_mutex.h:103
      (inlined by) packet::writePacket() at lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp:28
  #7  0x400d5136:0x3ffecde0 in minecraft::player::writeResponse() at lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp:392 (discriminator 3)     
  #8  0x400d54bf:0x3fff0890 in minecraft::player::join() at lib/minecraft/minecraft.cpp:670
  #9  0x400d2a81:0x3fff0910 in playerHandler(void*) at src/main.cpp:30 (discriminator 15)




ELF file SHA256: 352caedde0dc5df0

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
[    65][E][esConnecting to WiFi...
Connected to the WiFi network
172.20.10.5
[INFO] server started
```

I've checked with the following code in writePacket to make sure that mtx has been initalised:

```
if (mtx != nullptr) {
    Serial.println("Mutex pointer value: " + String((uintptr_t)mtx, HEX));
} else {
    Serial.println("Mutex pointer is nullptr");
}
```

And I get `Mutex pointer value: 35417578`, indicating it has initialised correctly.

Do you have any suggestions on what I do to allow the base64 favicon data to be processed correctly or is it simply a memory limit? If a memory limit, how do I know what this limit is?

Comment: 1) PROGRAM is for backward compatible with classic AVR chips like ATmega328, it doesn't need for ESP32 (and even modern AVR chips), as long as you declare the variable as `const` it will be save in flash and execute directly from flash, unless your code modify the variable, it will then load into RAM. 2) Not sure what packet you are referring to, but if it is network communication packet, the protocol it uses has a [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), you may need to read from flash and send in packet not large than a MTU in a loop.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67336657/4902099) to another question, it might be relevant to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think issue is in your `writeResponse` function:

for loop shold be `for (size_t i = 0; i < responseLength; i++)` instead
`for (size_t i = 0; i < responseLength; ++i)`

also increse `buffer` size in `packet` class if needed; currently, it is `buffer[6000]`.